# Wordpress update issue

Tags: wordpress

Downloading update from [https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip…](https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip%E2%80%A6)

The authenticity of wordpress-6.4.3-new-bundled.zip could not be verified as no signature was found.

Unpacking the update…

The update cannot be installed because some files could not be copied. This is usually due to inconsistent file permissions.: wp-admin/includes/update-core.php

Installation failed.  can someone help what to do with this issue;

Looking for a solution how to install the updates